# Как правильно добавить оператор своей структуре данных Python?

Tags: python, перегрузка-операторов

Предположим есть класс vector2:

```
class v2():
    x: int
    y: int
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x; self.y = y

    def __add__(self, other):
        self.x += other.x; self.y += other.y
        return self
```

В коде типа:

```
some_v2 = some_second_v2 = v2()
some_v2 += some_second_v2
```

Всё работает прекрасно

Но при:

```
A = B = v2()
C = A + B
```

`C` будет равно `A + B`, но при этом и к `A` прибавится `B`.

Как можно правильно определить оператор для в данном случае вектора, чтобы он корректно работал (в смысле как задумывалось, чтобы работал (Как например `int` в питоне))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `__add__` должен возвращать *новый объект* - результат сложения, а не изменять свой, например так:

```py
def __add__(self, other):
    return v2(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
```

Так, как у вас написан метод `__add__` должен выглядеть `__iadd__` (`+=`).